# Pausing after changing images in java as an animation

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have a function in a class that moves the Player one 32 by 32 tile. The local x and y values refer to (1,0),(0,1),(-1,0), or (0,-1) (referring to direction of movement). sprites is an array of buffered images referring to different sprites for walking. Player.x and Player.y are the the Player's current tile coordinates, and miniX and miniY are the amount of pixels the image is shifted. Swing.player is a JPanel that contains the image. currentSprite is the current spite being used.

```
        switch (2 * x + y) {
            case 2:
                Player.miniX = 4;
                currentSprite = sprites[10];
                Swing.player.repaint();
                //pause
                Player.miniX = 8;
                currentSprite = sprites[11];
                Swing.player.repaint();
                //pause
                Player.miniX = 12;
                Swing.player.repaint();
                currentSprite = sprites[10];
                Swing.player.repaint();
                //pause
                Player.miniX = 16;
                currentSprite = sprites[11];
                Swing.player.repaint();
                //pause
                Player.miniX = 20;
                currentSprite = sprites[10];
                Swing.player.repaint();
                //pause
                Player.miniX = 24;
                currentSprite = sprites[11];
                Swing.player.repaint();
                //pause
                Player.miniX = 28;
                currentSprite = sprites[10];
                Swing.player.repaint();
                //pause
                Player.miniX = 0;
                Player.x += 1;
                currentSprite = sprites[9];
                break;
            case 1:
                //omitted as is same as above
                break;
            case -1:
                //omitted as is same as above
                break;
            case -2:
                //omitted as is same as above
                break;
        }
```

What would be the best way to pause for a few milliseconds between each shift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Answer (score 0):

use this : `Thread.sleep(1000);`

This will make your current executing thread sleep for 1 sec i.e. 1000 milliseconds

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid that. If there isn't any other way I'll use it.

Comment: I believe it is the easiest way to pause. But why are you trying to avoid it. There are other methods as well but not so straight forward.

Comment: You can't use Thread.sleep(). That will cause the EDT to sleep so no painting will be done.